# javascript manual timer - the script is giving error : (TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null)

Tags: javascript

i don't understand why it is not taking value, it is giving type-error cannot take null value in console log

```js
var seconds = parseInt(document.getElementById('secs').innerHTML);
var timer;

function countdown() {
  var container = document.getElementById('dl');
  seconds--;
  if (seconds > 0) {
    container.innerHTML = 'Please wait <b>' + seconds + '</b> seconds..';
  } else {
    container.innerHTML = 'Time over';
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- <div id="dl"></div>
 <input type="button" onclick="setInterval(countdown, 1000);" id="dl" value="Start" /> -->

<input type="text" id="secs" placeholder="enter seconds" />
<input type="button" onclick="setInterval(countdown, 1000);" id="dl" value="Start" />
<div id="dl"></div>
```

Comment: seconds is not a number - because you need to get the .value of an input, not .innerHTML

Comment: i tried .value also, same result

Comment: because you're reading the value before a value is entered

Comment: then what should i do? please tell me.. i am trying this for a day now

Comment: use and learn from the code in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. `input` elements don't have a useful `innerHTML`, they have `value`.
2. You're trying to read from the input right away when your script runs. You want to wait until the user clicks the button.
3. You're never saving the interval's handle to `timer`
4. You have two elements with the `id` "dl". You can only have **one** element with a given `id` in the document.

See comments for where each is corrected below:

```js
// #1: Wait for user to click the button before reading the value
// Note we're using modern event handling, rather than onxyx attributes
document.getElementById("dl").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // #2: Use `value`, not `innerHTML`, with `input` elements
  var seconds = parseInt(document.getElementById('secs').value);
  // #3: Save the interval's handle to `timer`
  var timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

  function countdown() {
    var container = document.getElementById('count');
    seconds--;
    if (seconds > 0) {
      container.innerHTML = 'Please wait <b>' + seconds + '</b> seconds..';
    } else {
      container.innerHTML = 'Time over';
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="secs" placeholder="enter seconds" />
<input type="button" id="dl" value="Start" />
<!-- #4: Use a different ID for the timer output -->
<div id="count"></div>
```

---

You might also consider showing a message right away when the user clicks, instead of waiting for that first second. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...